# Can't define function member class of template class that returns the member class inside the source file (cpp)

Tags: c++

I have a class and a nested class:

```cpp
template<class T>
class foo
{
public:
    struct small_foo
    {
        small_foo& operator=(const small_foo& other);
    };
};
```

and a soruce file that looks like that:

```cpp
#include "foo.h"

template<class T>
foo<T>::small_foo& foo<T>::small_foo::operator=(const small_foo& other)
{
    //Some code
    return *this;
}
```

While im compiling (static library) I'm getting 3 errors and a warning:

> warning C4346:    :small_foo": name is not a type
>
> error C2061:    syntax error : identifier 'small_foo'
>
> error C2143:    syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
>
> error C2447:    '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)

EDIT:

The problem was that the compiler couldn't tell what `foo<T>::small_foo&` in `foo<T>::small_foo& foo<T>::small_foo::operator=(const small_foo& other)` was. The solution is to add typename keyword in front of it so it looks like that:

```cpp
template<class T>
typename foo<T>::small_foo& foo<T>::small_foo::operator=(const small_foo& other)
{
    //Some code
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Why is `#include "foo.h"` commented out?

Comment: @SergeyA While the OP will run into this issue (and I was certainly going to suggest they read that question), it doesn't seem to be a duplicate, since the error they're getting is not related to it.

Comment: It's just to show that there is an include, the name isn't exactly "foo.h"

Comment: So is the template definition visible (i.e. its header file included), or not? Commented-out code suggests it's NOT.

Comment: It is included, wait let me edit the post so it's clear.

Comment: My guess is that it could be related to return value of the operator=() function.

Comment: Your template definition is missing a terminating semi-colon.

Comment: Sorry, that's not the issue. I've rewritten the code here to not include other functions, the semi-colons are in included in my code and I've updated the post.

Comment: If you change the function header in the source file by prepending `typename` to it, does the error go away?

Comment: Error wen't away when I moved it to .hpp file.

Comment: I only moved 2 functions with "foo<T>::small_foo&" as a return type.

Comment: So your problem is solved, and since the question is closed, nothing more needs to happen here on SO. However, I suggest you also read [this question on templates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/1782465), because I strongly believe that was the original error in your code.

Comment: The solution is to add `typename` keyword in front of `foo<T>::small_foo&`